# Is it possible to remove the delay on wrong password?

Tags: security, password

So I type my password incorrectly from time to time. Sometimes for `sudo` sometimes for logging in to my (Ubuntu) machine.

In either case, there is a two or three second delay before it gives me a second chance.

I understand that this is a security feature, but I'm curious if this could be disabled for the first failed attempt.

Comment: It's supposed to be a delay, it's a security feature.  In case someone tried a dictionary-attack (just trying words from a dictionary) or similar; that imposed delay between tries, would make such an attack *very* time-consuming... which is the point of the delay.  You could probably remove the delay by "fixing" the source-code of pam, passwd or sudo; but why make your system less secure?

Comment: @BaardKopperud I tried to explain that I understand the security issue, but I'm thinking that if the _first_ failed attempt didn't have the delay, the security of the machine would not be significantly compromised.

Comment: The suggested duplicate should answer the question. See the 2nd answer, not the accepted one.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following settings, found here:
http://fooninja.net/2010/10/07/get-rid-of-wrong-password-delay-in-linux/

**Disable delay in Ubuntu and Debian:**

Edit /etc/pam.d/common-auth and add nodelay:
e.g.:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

changed to

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure nodelay
```

**Disable delay in CentOS, RHEL and Fedora:**

Edit /etc/pam.d/system-auth and add nodelay:
e.g.:

```
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
```

changed to:

```
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass nodelay
```